# OpenCV Python - integer argument expected, got float

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to run a Seamless Clone function from like this...

```
# Read images : src image will be cloned into dst
im = cv2.imread('background.jpg')
obj= cv2.imread('object.png')

# Create an all white mask
mask = 255 * np.ones(obj.shape, obj.dtype)

# The location of the center of the src in the dst
width, height, channels = im.shape
center = (height/2, width/2)

# Seamlessly clone src into dst and put the results in output
normal_clone = cv2.seamlessClone(obj, im, mask, center, cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)
mixed_clone = cv2.seamlessClone(obj, im, mask, center, cv2.MIXED_CLONE)

# Write results
cv2.imwrite("output_images/opencv-normal-clone-example.jpg", normal_clone)
cv2.imwrite("output_images/opencv-mixed-clone-example.jpg", mixed_clone)
```

But it is giving me the error...

```
integer argument expected, got float
```

Any ideas how I can find out which one of the arguments it does not like?

Comment: I have a feeling it's coming from your ```center = (height/2, width/2)``` calculation. If you happen to give it an odd number, it could produce a non-integer number, and the ```seamlessClone()``` function is probably expecting an integer. You could try passing in fake numbers that are even, compile, and see if you get the same error.

Comment: or use `center=(height//2, width//2)`.

Comment: Have tried forcing center with center=(250,250) but still get the assertion failed error

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

when I kept the center as integers this way of dividing by 2, it worked:-

center = (height>>1, width>>1)